# How to get a class for list of objects of some type with Reflection to use it as a parameter when looking for a specific method

Tags: java, reflection

Hello, I have a class:

```java
package com.example.test;

public class Test {
    public static void doSomething(Object[] objects) {
        return;
    }
}
```

what I want to do is to get that class (and invoke later) with reflection. The problem is that I have the name of method and type of param given as Strings. Here is the code that I tried to solve this issue with:

```java
String methodName = "doSomething";
String paramType = "java.lang.Object";
try {
    Class<?> paramTypeClass = Class.forName(paramType);
    com.example.test.Test.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, paramTypeClass);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

it throws a NoSuchMethodException:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.test.Test.doSomething(java.lang.Object)

I also tried with paramType set to "java.lang.Object...", but it throws this on the 4th line of my code above:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java/lang/Object///

also with "java.lang.Object[]":

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java/lang/Object[]

What should I put as the methodName, or how can I change my code in a different way to solve this problem?

Comment: If a class name is "java.lang.Object", then the name of an array of that type is named as follows:
  "[L" + class name + ";"
or, in this case: "[Ljava.lang.Object;"

Comment: @Dwb, I forgot to thank you :) It really helped me, thanks.